# Start Java EE Server with JPA even when db server is not running

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, glassfish-3

We have some Glassfish Applications that need a db connection to initialize some values in memory when they start but later on do not need them to do their job.

In the moment we try to start them even when the db connection fails. We have made a backup of the data into a file on the harddrive of the glassfish machine. When the db is off we use the file instead.

The problem is now that the glassfish server want's a db connection when it starts. There is no way that we can catch the exception and go on with plan b ("loading the file"). The exception is a UnknownHostException.

Can I somehow configure the connection pool or the JPA so that the start of the server does not fail.

Thanks a lot for you help.